# Dash active cell content on dash table filter

Tags: python, pandas, plotly-dash

I have a Dashtable which has more than 1000 rows across multiple pages. I need to show the content of active cell by clicking on it.
It is working fine as along as I am not filtering the rows in dash table. As soon I apply the filter (filter the rows with some data) and click on the cell in the table, it shows me the old cell reference which means it is not displaying the content of the newly selected position but the old reference.

''''''''

- **# call back function

  ```
  @app.callback([Output('textareaReq', 'children')],
                [Input('srctable', 'active_cell')],
                [State('srctable', 'data')])
  # code for active cell click
  def get_active_cell_content(active_cell, data):

      if active_cell:`enter code here`
          location = active_cell
          strRow = data[location['row']]
          strActiveCell = strRow[location['column_id']]

           if strActiveCell:


              msg = strActiveCell
              return (html.P(msg))**
  ```

'''''''''''''''
Pls note I am displaying the output in text area

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, but in case someone else comes looking for the answer, I managed to get this working as I was having the same issues.

Plotly (now?) lets you assign an ID column to a data table, so that when your table is filtered or sorted you can use this ID to reference the specific row, rather than relying on row number:

`df['id'] = df['your_id_column']`

Then, inside your callback, you can print the `active_cell` and get the `id` returned as `row_id`, which will adjust correctly when the data table is filtered and sorted:

`{'row': 1, 'column': 11, 'column_id': 'reason', 'row_id': 'H_195202'}`

Link to the relevant article. Hope this helps!

https://dash.plotly.com/datatable/interactivity